# How to create a report in oracle report builder with text displayed only at the bottom of last page

Tags: oracle, report

I am having a boilerplate text that should be printed on bottom of the last page of the report. But report builder wouldn't let me have the "print object on" property to "last" due to the reason suggested here: http://oracle.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/oracle-apps-l/error-while-setting-one-frame-property-to-last-page-914513
The solution/workaround seems to be there in a link in that page but it isn't displayed by the site it seems. If someone has a workaround please help me out here.

Edit: The boiler plate text should be outside the margin as per the requirement along with the page number.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the "workaround" but the way I'd do this is put the object in the normal print area, set `Print Object On` to `Last Page`, and change the margin so that it will be printed at the correct location. The page number will still be in the margin, but you can offset it back into the page area to sit on the same line as the boilerplate text if you wish.

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|                                                |
|                     margin                     |
|   +----------------------------------------+   |
| m |                                        | m |
| a |                                        | a |
| r |                                        | r |
| g |                                        | g |
| i |                                        | i |
| n |                                        | n |
|   |                                        |   |
|   |                                        |   |
|   |                                        |   |
|   |Boilerplate Text (Last Page)     PageNo |   |
|   +----------------------------------------+   |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

The "`Boilerplate Text (Last Page)`" bit is defined within the report page area, whereas the "`PageNo`" bit is defined in the margin area. Notice how I've reduced the bottom margin height.

Answer (score 0):

i think i did something like that recently by checking if 'current page' == 'last page'

use 2 page number fields and a format trigger.

if i can find my old example i'll update this later.